TV shows not showing on Up Next
If I want to watch a TV show (or a movie) that is in a family shared account. I am able to watch it, but it does not display in "up next" nor does it remember when I was up to in the movie. It always starts back at the start, and TV shows just never show up there.
One way around it I’ve found is to search the store for it, and play it from there.
However I have a show that seems to be discontinued on the store, so I cannot search for it, even though I can play it.
If there a way to get family shared items to show up in "up next" like movies and tv shows that are in my own account do?
